# Call to undefined function str_getcsv()

Tags: php, function, version

I get this error

> Call to undefined function str_getcsv()

It seems to be a php version. it didn't come out until version 5.3

Anyone know a way replace this function instead upgrade the PHP version?

Comment: check the manual first http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php

Comment: write your string to php://temp then rewind and use f_getcsv()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know if this actually works, but on the manual page there is some example implementation which you can use as a fallback like this:

```
if(!function_exists('str_getcsv')) {
    function str_getcsv($input, $delimiter = ',', $enclosure = '"') {

        if( ! preg_match("/[$enclosure]/", $input) ) {
          return (array)preg_replace(array("/^\\s*/", "/\\s*$/"), '', explode($delimiter, $input));
        }

        $token = "##"; $token2 = "::";
        //alternate tokens "\034\034", "\035\035", "%%";
        $t1 = preg_replace(array("/\\\[$enclosure]/", "/$enclosure{2}/",
             "/[$enclosure]\\s*[$delimiter]\\s*[$enclosure]\\s*/", "/\\s*[$enclosure]\\s*/"),
             array($token2, $token2, $token, $token), trim(trim(trim($input), $enclosure)));

        $a = explode($token, $t1);
        foreach($a as $k=>$v) {
            if ( preg_match("/^{$delimiter}/", $v) || preg_match("/{$delimiter}$/", $v) ) {
                $a[$k] = trim($v, $delimiter); $a[$k] = preg_replace("/$delimiter/", "$token", $a[$k]); }
        }
        $a = explode($token, implode($token, $a));
        return (array)preg_replace(array("/^\\s/", "/\\s$/", "/$token2/"), array('', '', $enclosure), $a);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aha, I found this code snippet in [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)

```
<?php 
if (!function_exists('str_getcsv')) { 
    function str_getcsv($input, $delimiter = ',', $enclosure = '"', $escape = '\\', $eol = '\n') { 
        if (is_string($input) && !empty($input)) { 
            $output = array(); 
            $tmp    = preg_split("/".$eol."/",$input); 
            if (is_array($tmp) && !empty($tmp)) { 
                while (list($line_num, $line) = each($tmp)) { 
                    if (preg_match("/".$escape.$enclosure."/",$line)) { 
                        while ($strlen = strlen($line)) { 
                            $pos_delimiter       = strpos($line,$delimiter); 
                            $pos_enclosure_start = strpos($line,$enclosure); 
                            if ( 
                                is_int($pos_delimiter) && is_int($pos_enclosure_start) 
                                && ($pos_enclosure_start < $pos_delimiter) 
                                ) { 
                                $enclosed_str = substr($line,1); 
                                $pos_enclosure_end = strpos($enclosed_str,$enclosure); 
                                $enclosed_str = substr($enclosed_str,0,$pos_enclosure_end); 
                                $output[$line_num][] = $enclosed_str; 
                                $offset = $pos_enclosure_end+3; 
                            } else { 
                                if (empty($pos_delimiter) && empty($pos_enclosure_start)) { 
                                    $output[$line_num][] = substr($line,0); 
                                    $offset = strlen($line); 
                                } else { 
                                    $output[$line_num][] = substr($line,0,$pos_delimiter); 
                                    $offset = ( 
                                                !empty($pos_enclosure_start) 
                                                && ($pos_enclosure_start < $pos_delimiter) 
                                                ) 
                                                ?$pos_enclosure_start 
                                                :$pos_delimiter+1; 
                                } 
                            } 
                            $line = substr($line,$offset); 
                        } 
                    } else { 
                        $line = preg_split("/".$delimiter."/",$line); 

                        /* 
                         * Validating against pesky extra line breaks creating false rows. 
                         */ 
                        if (is_array($line) && !empty($line[0])) { 
                            $output[$line_num] = $line; 
                        }  
                    } 
                } 
                return $output; 
            } else { 
                return false; 
            } 
        } else { 
            return false; 
        } 
    } 
} 
?>
```

Comment: You are still using `str_getcsv`

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing it with `fgetcsv()` although you'd have to open the file into stream to be able to read it.

Example:

```
$fh = fopen('php://temp', 'r+');
fwrite($fh, $string);
rewind($fh);

$row = fgetcsv($fh);

fclose($fh);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the above code snippets do not properly parse csv files where the entries are contained in quotes and contain commas themselves.

But you can combine the other responses here into something that worked for me.

Basically, if the str_getcsv function isn't defined, define it yourself, and its implementation should create an in-memory file handle that is then passed to fgetcsv.  For some reason PHP on GoDaddy (where I'm hosting a site) doesn't have str_getcsv but DOES have fgetcsv.  Go figure.

```
if (!function_exists('str_getcsv')) { 
    function str_getcsv($input, $delimiter = ',', $enclosure = '"', $escape = '\\', $eol = '\n') { 
        $fh = fopen('php://temp', 'r+');
        fwrite($fh, $input);
        rewind($fh);

        $row = fgetcsv($fh);

        fclose($fh);
        return $row;
    } 
}
```